# Is there a way in Mysql to extract string from second occurrence of a dynamic length

Tags: mysql

In MySql DB, I have a column of string like

```
xx-11|Hello Shrishti|@KFC near you|Bhopal|...
```

with varying fields concatenated by the pipe operator '|'.
Sometimes there are no extra fields like `"xx-22|Hello Chandu"`.

I want to extract the string after the second occurrence of '|' if extra fields are present, and an empty string if no extra fields are present.

Can anyone please help me with any logic. I have tried `INSTR`, `SUBSTR`, etc. but I could not come up with the proper solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use two calls to `LOCATE to get the position of the 2nd` |`, and` SUBSTR()` to get everything after that.

```
SUBSTR(columnName, LOCATE('|', columName, LOCATE('|', columName)+1)+1)
```

If you're using MySQL 8.x, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()`

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(columnName, '^[^|]*\\|[^|]*\\|', '')
```

The regexp matches from the beginning of `^` to the second `|`.

Comment: the problem is there is no definite value to give to N , as the number of fields are varying in the string

Comment: It doesn't matter how many fields there are, as long as you just want a specific one.

Comment: You said you want to get the 3rd field, so `N=3`

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood the question. You want *all* the fields starting with 3.

Comment: Yeah correct, i wanted string from 3 rd field and ' ' when no field is present.